# How can I rotate a graph that contains an imshow in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some microscopic scan data in a rectangular grid that was scanned by an X/Y scanner. The object I'm scanning contains markers in a nice, rectangular, orthogonal pattern on its surface.

Due to practicalities, we can only align the object to the X/Y scanner to within a few degrees when fixing it to the X/Y scanner table. We compensate for this by some calibration measurement, and then performing scans that are nicely aligned with the object we're trying to scan (by moving the X and Y axes simultaneously).

This works well, but now I want to display this data in a coordinate system that corresponds to the X/Y scanner's axes. So the scanned, rectangular dataset will be rotated a bit in that coordinate system. (See the second image below for what I mean).

For presentation purposes however, I would prefer to have the scanned image nicely horizontal, and the axes rotated. I am trying to accomplish this in Matplotlib but I'm failing miserably.

I can get a rotated Axes (see the third image), but I am unable to figure out what kind of transforms I should do to get the ax3.imshow() to show its data at its intended position.

Here's where I am so far:

[image: output of the program]

The program to generate the test data and the image I have so far is shown below.

I'd appreciate any help I can get. I'm afraid to say the documentation of matplotlib leaves a lot to be desired, so I hope somebody who knows matplotlib inside out may chime in.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes

import random

angle_deg = 5.0 # degrees CCW.

# Test data

NX = 5
NY = 3

x = np.zeros(shape=(NY, NX))
y = np.zeros(shape=(NY, NX))
c = np.zeros(shape=(NY, NX))

angle_rad = np.deg2rad(angle_deg)

for iy in range(NY):
    for ix in range(NX):

        icx = 0.5 * (NX - 1)
        icy = 0.5 * (NY - 1)

        # To centered coordinates, in physical units
        xcp = (ix - icx) * 0.1
        ycp = (iy - icy) * 0.1

        # Rotate
        xcpr = xcp * np.cos(angle_rad) - ycp * np.sin(angle_rad)
        ycpr = xcp * np.sin(angle_rad) + ycp * np.cos(angle_rad)

        # Rotate, and translated to the physical center
        x[iy, ix] = xcpr + 40.0
        y[iy, ix] = ycpr + 30.0

        c[iy, ix] = 100 + ix + iy

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 9)

# Add axis #1.

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax1.set_title("imshow()")
ax1.imshow(c, origin='lower')
ax1.grid()

# Add axis #2.

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
ax2.set_title("pcolormesh()")
ax2.pcolormesh(x, y, c, shading='nearest')
ax2.axis('equal')
ax2.grid()

# Add axis #3.

min_x = x.min()
max_x = x.max()
min_y = y.min()
max_y = y.max()

cx = 0.5 * (min_x + max_x)
cy = 0.5 * (min_y + max_y)

transform = Affine2D().rotate_deg(-angle_deg)

grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(transform, extremes=(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y))

ax3 = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, 133, grid_helper=grid_helper)
ax3.grid()
ax3.set_title("rotate the entire graph.\nHow do I do get the data to show up here,\nhorizontally like in the leftmost image!?\n")

ax3.imshow(c, origin='lower')

fig.add_subplot(ax3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I half feel like doing this another way could be easier. Can you create a standard, transparent svg grid and several of the XY scanner images, then using Inkscape or something perform the precise positioning you want, then edit the SVG text with python to replace the image sources and export them to pdfs or pngs?

Comment: I need to be able to do this repetitively and automatically. This is not about creating a single picture.

Comment: You didn't understand what I suggested. In the SVG XML you can specify the rotation, position and image link source. I'm suggesting you create the base images you have in matplotlib, then, in another script, place them in the SVG with the appropriate transform. E.g. `xlink:href="test.png"`, `transform="rotate(-13)"`, then you export them with, e.g. subprocess call `inkscape f"C:\path\img{n}.svg" --export-filename=f"C:\path\test_{n}.png"`

Comment: I am looking for a self-contained matplotlib solution. Taking on an inkscape dependency for something that's probably less than 10 lines of code would be excessive.